# Proof that $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ is locally Liptschitz

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:(0, 1] \to \Bbb R$ given by $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$, I want to show that $f$ is locally Liptschitz, this means (for $\lambda>0$, and $x, y \in B(p;r)$)

$$|\sqrt x-\sqrt y| \leq \lambda |x-y|$$
If we take $x, y \in B(0, r)$ for any $r>0$, then $|x|<r$ and $|y|<r$. As $x,y \in (0, 1]$ then $|\sqrt{x}|<|x|$ and $|\sqrt{y}|<|y|$ from this maybe I can say that:

$$|\sqrt x-\sqrt y| \leq |\sqrt{x}|+|\sqrt{y}| \leq |x| + |y|=2r$$

But I think this is not my goal as such. Any suggestions to even out the inequality?

Comment: **HINT:** Consider multiplying by $1 = \dfrac{\sqrt x+\sqrt y} {\sqrt x+\sqrt y}$.

Comment: More generally, every $C^1$ function is locally LIpschitz (by the extreme-value theorem applied to the derivative, followed by mean-value theorem to relate the bound on the derivative to differences in the original function).

Comment: The square root function is not Lipschitz near 0: $\sqrt{x}>x$ for any $x\in (0,1)$ and the lower bound fails (alternatively look at the tangent lines near $x=0$). It will be Lipschitz however on any interval $(\epsilon,1]$ for any $0<\epsilon<1$; maybe this is what is meant by locally Lipschitz in $(0,1]$?

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks for your contribution, but now I find it a little difficult to find  $\lambda>0$ s.t. $\frac{1}{|\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}|} \leq \lambda$

Comment: You do not want $x,y\in B(0,r)$. On the contrary, you want $x,y\ge r>0$.